I’m looking for a writing guide that suits me better
Encounters: Essays for Exploration and Inquiry is a writing guide that provides all kinds of essays for reference. Unfortunately, it has been out of print, which is why I came here asking for a similarly organized guidebook. Here is the introduction to this book on the website:

With pedagogy that encourages students to respond to print and visual texts, Encounters provides a spectrum of provocative and beautifully written student and professional essays.
Alphabetically organized, this versatile reader for first year writing courses offers a strong selection of student essays. The approach emphasizes the writing process and the craft of writing. Professional readings are organized to build from the informal essay to formal academic and argument writing. There is a section on reading and writing about artwork and photography that explains how to analyze paintings and photographs.

Anyone knows this book and is willing to recommend something similar?

What do you mean, "it has been out of print, which is why" you try to find another book. The book you mentions can be bought used. I find several offers online. There's no need to find another book. If this is the book you want, buy it used. Or find it in a library.

That description doesn't give a lot of information. For those who haven't read the book, it would be more useful if you stated what you want from a book, why you want it, what you are studying, etc.
